# tkinter - Change menubar location

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program thats like a desktop enviroment with educational games and I was wondering how to put the menubar on the bottom of the window.

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, if you're talking about the native menubar you get when you set the `menu` attribute of the root window.

You can create your own menubar that behaves a little bit like a menubar by using a frame and one or more menubuttons, and place that at the bottom.

Comment: Could you give me an idea of how to make a menubar with a frame and have the same menubar attributes?